# how to create a joystick in flutter which can only move in four different direction?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation, joystick

I want to create a ball game in flutter like this: The user can slide the ball in four different directions on the fixed path ( the grey plus sign ) and change the direction when the ball is in the center it's like an old joystick thing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Joystick package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_joystick

Set the mode horizontal and JoyStickMode.horizontalAndVertical and design the background